# Android's ListView autosize

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, textview

I have a `ListView` with multiple `TextView`s. Notice that sometimes these `TextView`s are not all used.
Still the single listings of the `ListView` do always have the same size.

How can I change it in a way such that the `ListView` only takes the space necessary?

Comment: well i suppose you could make the individual row heights of the listview set to "wrap_content". But is it your intention to have listview with purposefully empty rows?

Comment: you have to make layout_height ="0dip"
and the layout weight =1;
hope this help :)

Comment: hmm... @Angie, no it does not work. Too sad :(

Comment: is you item composed with multiple textviews or your listview composed with multiple items(every item is a textview?)?